# verify $R(T)=R^2$(Let $T:R^3 \rightarrow R^2$ be the linear mapping defined by $T(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(a_1-a_2,2a_3)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T:R^3 \rightarrow R^2$ be the linear mapping defined by $T(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(a_1-a_2,2a_3)$.

I want to verify $R(T)=R^2$

So $R(T)=T(x)=T(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(a_1-a_2,2a_3)$
Since it is closed under scalar multiplication and addition, $(a_1-a_2,2a_3)$ is indeed in $R^2$, so $R(T)=R^2$. Is that the right way of saying?

Comment: do you want to verify that $T$ maps $\mathbb R^3$ *onto* $\mathbb R^2$?  if so, one way to see that is to note that any $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ has pre-image $(x,0,y/2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that, in order to complete your proof, you need to show that

$\dim R(T) = 2; \tag 1$

you have already shown that

$R(T) \subset \Bbb R^2 \tag 2$

is a subspace; if (1) is established, then we have

$R(T) = \Bbb R^2, \tag 3$

since a two-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ must be the whole thing.

This can simply be done by setting

$a_1 = 1, \; a_2 = 0, \; a_3 = 0, \tag 4$

so that

$(a_1 - a_2, 2a_3) = (1, 0) \in R(T), \tag 5$

and then by taking

$a_1 = a_2, \; a_3 = \dfrac{1}{2}, \tag 6$

whence

$(a_1 - a_2, 2a_3) = (0, 1) \in R(T), \tag 7$

so that $R(T)$ contains the basis

$\{(1, 0), (0, 1) \}, \tag 8$

which shows that (1), and hence (3), binds.

On the other hand we may directly take, for any

$(b_1, b_2) \in \Bbb R^2, \tag 9$

$a_1 = a_2 + b_1, \; a_3 =  \dfrac{b_2}{2};  \tag{10}$

thus

$(a_1 - a_2, 2a_3) = (b_1, b_2) \in \Bbb R^2, \tag {11}$

and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, then we are given that $T:\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}^2$ is defined by letting

$$T(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1-x_2,2x_3)$$

for all $x_1,x_2,x_3\in\Bbb{R}$, and we need to show that $\text{Range}(T)=\Bbb{R}^2$.

Note that $T(1,0,0)=(1,0)$ and $T\left(0,0,\frac{1}{2}\right)=(0,1)$. Since $(1,0),(0,1)\in\text{Range}(T)$, we have that

$$\text{Range}(T)\supseteq\text{Span}\left\{(1,0),(0,1)\right\}=\Bbb{R}^2.$$

Hence $\text{Range}(T)=\Bbb{R}^2$.

Note: the above argument will work as long as the scalars don't come from a field of characteristic $2$.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to see that for any $(x,y)\in R^2$ the triple $(x,0,{y\over 2})\in R^3$ maps to $(x,y)$ and thus it is surjective i.e. $R(T) = R^2$.